# Applying an image to a curved surface

Tags: textures, blender

I want to apply an image or texture onto my car model, but I didn't find a way of applying it to the surface like you would do with a sticker for example. I tried using the stencil and other texture draw tools but all of those seem to not warp the image.

[image: Stencil layout]

[image: Actual looks]

The problem is I can't apply it to the unwrapped 2D texture, because it stretches on multiple different parts and I'm not allowed to unwrap it in a different way.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is Vertex Paint.
Texture Paint in Blender only project what you paint from viewport that why it stretch when you paint on face which not face direct to viewport.